# Read a particular string from text file and then print the the value for it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to read a particular value from a text file and then print the value in front of it using only batch scripting.

The script should read only all "Total Space" encountered under Aggregate Column in the text file and then add and report the values under the Allocated Col.

cannot gawk as it is not allowed to install any third party software on the mgmt server i am trying to run my script.

TEXT GOES LIKE THIS...

```
Total space    WAFL reserve    Snap reserve    Usable space       BSR NVLOG           A-SIS          Smtape
    13245GB          1324GB           596GB         11325GB             0GB             6GB             0GB

Space allocated to volumes in the aggregate

Volume                          Allocated            Used       Guarantee
vol0                                301GB             6GB          volume
groups                               18GB            18GB            none
userdata                            665GB           662GB            none
restricted                            9GB             4GB            none
local                                16GB            10GB            none

Aggregate                       Allocated            Used           Avail
Total space                        1011GB           701GB         10306GB
Snap reserve                        596GB             7GB           588GB
WAFL reserve                       1324GB            94GB          1230GB


Total space    WAFL reserve    Snap reserve    Usable space       BSR NVLOG          A-SIS          Smtape
     4138GB           413GB             0GB          3724GB             0GB           20GB             0GB

Space allocated to volumes in the aggregate

Volume                          Allocated            Used       Guarantee
uservol01                           706GB           701GB            none
deptvol02                           367GB           364GB            none
deptvol01                           837GB           834GB            none

Aggregate                       Allocated            Used           Avail
Total space                        1911GB          1900GB          1792GB
Snap reserve                          0GB             0GB             0GB
WAFL reserve                        413GB            41GB           372GB

Aggregate 'aggr0'

Total space    WAFL reserve    Snap reserve    Usable space       BSR NVLOG          A-SIS          Smtape
      827GB            82GB             0GB           744GB             0GB            0GB             0GB

Space allocated to volumes in the aggregate

Volume                          Allocated            Used       Guarantee
vol0                                710GB            10GB          volume

Aggregate                       Allocated            Used           Avail
Total space                         710GB            10GB            32GB
Snap reserve                          0GB             1GB             0GB
WAFL reserve                         82GB             4GB            78GB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET tot=0
SET "agg="
FOR /f "tokens=1-3" %%a IN (yourreport.txt) DO (
 IF %%a%%b==Totalspace CALL :process %%c
 IF %%a%%b==AggregateAllocated SET agg=Y
)
ECHO total: %tot%GB
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET val=%1
SET val=%val:~0,-2%
SET /a tot+=val
SET "agg="
GOTO :eof
```

Your requirement is muddy. There is no apparent "Aggregate" column. Had you said that this should add the xxx, yyy and zzz producing abcd, it would have been clearer. As it is, this solution is a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk):

```
$1=="Aggregate" {flag=1}
$1=="Total" && flag==1 {sum=$3}
$1=="Snap" && flag==1 {sum+=$3}
$1=="WAFL" && flag=1 {sum+=$3; flag=0; i++; print "Volume"i, sum"GB"}
```

---

```
>awk -f script file
Volume1 2931GB
Volume2 2324GB
Volume3 792GB
```

[awk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)